# Is it possible to ignore NULL values when using LAG() and LEAD() functions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

As you know the LAG() & LEAD() analytic functions access data from a previous and next row in the same result set without the use of a self-join. But is it possible to ignore NULL values until access to a NOT NULL value?

Answer (score 6):

Its possible using window functions.
Have a read of this [article](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle) by Itzik Ben-Gan for more details.

In the code below, the cte is getting the most recent NOT NULL id value, then the next select gets the actual column value. This example uses LAG.
eg.

```
-- DDL for T1
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE tempdb;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T1', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.T1;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY,
col1 INT NULL
);

-- Small set of sample data
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.T1;

INSERT INTO dbo.T1(id, col1) VALUES
( 2, NULL),
( 3,   10),
( 5,   -1),
( 7, NULL),
(11, NULL),
(13,  -12),
(17, NULL),
(19, NULL),
(23, 1759);

;WITH C AS
(
SELECT
    id, 
    col1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN id END) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS grp
FROM dbo.T1
)
SELECT
    id, 
    col1, 
    (SELECT col1 FROM dbo.T1 WHERE id = grp) lastval    
FROM C;
```

Comment: `Update:` Source Article URL:
[https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 11 supports the option `ignore nulls` which does exactly what you want.  Of course, your question is about SQL Server, but sometimes it is heartening to know that the functionality does exist somewhere.

It is possible to simulate this functionality.  The idea is to assign null values to a group, based on the preceding value.  In essence, this is counting the number of non-null values before it.  You can do this with a correlated subquery.  Or, more interestingly, with the difference of two row numbers.  Then within the group, you can just use `max()`.

I think the following does what you want.  Assume that `col` contains `NULL` values and `ordering` has the ordering for the rows:

```
select t.*,
       max(col) over (partition by grp) as LagOnNull
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by ordering) - 
              row_number() over (partition by col order by ordering)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t;
```

The `lead()` is similar but the ordering is reversed.  And, this will work with additional partitioning keys, but you need to add them to all the window expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. But I can't understand whats 'col2' in this sample?

Comment: `col2` should have been `col`, the argument to `lag()`/`lead()`.

Comment: Creative solution Gordon. But unfortunately didn't work for me :(

Comment: @Mostapha777 . . . This does work to ignore `NULL`s for a `lag()` of 1 (which I should have mentioned in the answer).  If it doesn't work for you, you should edit your question with the query you tried.  You have to get the partitioning clauses right on the various analytic functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
LEAD(IIF(col1 IS NULL,NULL, col1),1) OVER PARTITION BY (ISNULL(col1))
```